# PHP : include_once file not reading POST data

Tags: php, forms, post, include

I have 4 files -
1. form.php
2. index.php
3.mobile.php
4. desktop.php

form.php send form data by post method and index.php should recieve it and it is recieving. But problem is...
index.php include file mobile.php or desktop.php according to user's device and uses include_once() method to do this. But the included file is not reading posted data. What is the solution?

Comment: included files do have access to posted variables. Without seeing your code and what you are doing it is impossible to know what is going on. You should break down your problem into as simple of a case as you can and test that. Then build up from there to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As long as $_POST array is populated and not unset by some code, it is perfectly accessible everywhere.

Of course you should include PHP files, not HTTP resources, though.